# Mapping lambda for Class<in Throwable> in HashMap

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to create a map which maps exception classes' types and associates a function to execute later.

```
sealed class HttpErrors(open var errorMessage: String = String()) : Throwable()
class UnauthorizedError(override var errorMessage: String) : HttpErrors()
class BadRequestError(override var errorMessage: String) : HttpErrors()

fun handleErrors(actions: HashMap<Class<out Throwable>, () -> Unit>){
...
}
```

I insert in map and pass it to a function:

```
override fun getItems() {
        ...
        val actions = hashMapOf(BadRequestError::class.java to {presenter.log("Info")})
        ...
        .onDefaultSchedulers(actions)
```

And my which receives the map:

```
fun <T> Single<T>.onDefaultSchedulers(actions: HashMap<Class<in Throwable>, () -> Unit>): Single<T>
```

But editor complains saying:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
kotlin.collections.HashMap<Class<in Throwable>, () → Unit> /* = java.util.HashMap<Class<in Throwable>, () → Unit> */
Found:
kotlin.collections.HashMap<Class<BadRequestError>, () → Unit> /* = java.util.HashMap<Class<BadRequestError>, () → Unit> */
```

I didn't understand this complain if BadRequestError inherits from Throwable.

Comment: `in` means contravariant. The acceptable type hierarchy is inverted from something that has a covariant `out` type (like `List` always has). For instance, a function that operates on a `<in T: Int>` can't work on supertypes of `Int`, such as `Number`, because it might be using a function of `Int` that `Number` doesn't have.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Fixed. Even with out I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal version of your code which reproduces the error you have observed:

```
/* does not compile */

sealed class HttpErrors : Throwable()

class BadRequestError : HttpErrors()

fun onDefaultSchedulers(actions: HashMap<Class<out Throwable>, () -> Unit>) {}

fun getItems() {
    val actions = hashMapOf(BadRequestError::class.java to {})
    onDefaultSchedulers(actions)  // <- type mismatch
}
```

To make it work, the `actions` parameter of `onDefaultSchedulers` requires a two-level covariance,

1. on the outer `Class<...>` and
2. on the inner `Throwable`.

So if you declare it as `HashMap<`**`out`** `Class<out Throwable>, ...` the code compiles:

```
/* compiles */

sealed class HttpErrors : Throwable()

class BadRequestError : HttpErrors()

fun onDefaultSchedulers(actions: HashMap<out Class<out Throwable>, () -> Unit>) {}

fun getItems() {
    val actions = hashMapOf(BadRequestError::class.java to {})
    onDefaultSchedulers(actions)
}
```